# Interactive, tabbed live tail of multiple files?

Tags: vim, tail

I'm often tailing multiple files, and even with a terminal multiplexer (ie tmux or screen) it's still annoying to have multiple windows/shell sessions dedicated to watching multiple files.

Is there something akin to Vim's tabbed mode which would allow me to watch multiple files in real time, being able to change tabs between open files?

Something like this would be awesome:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `multitail`

Should be available on most standard repositories

As a point of clarification, I don't believe it does `tabs` but it opens multiple files in `splits`, and will give you live feeds of those files. works beautifully for what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's nice, as it helps me avoid using multiple sessions for multiple tails, but it, in effect, simply mimics what I'm able to do with my terminal multiplexer (split windows). I'll see if there's any tabbed option or if I can configure `vim` to do it right.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Check my edit, hehe, use the `set autoread` function in vim :)

Comment: Will autoread follow the end of the file, too?

Comment: ah, actually on deeper investigation `autoread` does not meet the functionality you require. sorry about that. I'll see if I can find another option, Let me know if you find something before I do hah.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea of using a java-based tool to achieve this isn't too repugnant, try [follow](http://follow.sourceforge.net/)

[image: screenshot of follow utility]

Comment: I have to admit that it's at least a _little_ repugnant, but the main issue is that I'm usually doing admin work on remote machines over SSH. _Sure_ I could X forward, but _X-forwarding a Java program?_ I don't know how I'd sleep at night after doing that.